# Convert sparse matrice in list of list in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to convert a sparse matrice in list of non zero index like this :

```
>>> row = array([0,2,2,0,1,2])
>>> col = array([0,0,1,2,2,2])
>>> data = array([1,1,1,1,1,1])
>>> mat = csc_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(3,3) )
>>> mat.todense() 
matrix([[1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]])
>>> convert(mat)
[[0, 2],[2],[0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: It's unclear to me how the output of `convert` relates to `mat`.

Comment: I'll state it more strongly: I have no idea how the output of `convert` relates to `mat`, or perhaps more importantly, to the input `row`/`col`/`data`.

Comment: a list of non zero index

Comment: Oh, right, you changed the third value of the output as well. Sorry, hadn't seen that.

Comment: @zedouard: Are you looking for the non-zero entries, or rather for the entries occurring in the sparsity pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
>>> 
>>> row = array([0,2,2,0,1,2])
>>> col = array([0,0,1,2,2,2])
>>> data = array([1,1,1,1,1,1])
>>> mat = csc_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(3,3) )
>>> [list(line.nonzero()[1]) for line in mat]
[[0, 2], [2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

would help?  You should probably look at [nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), anyway.

Comment: Yes, i'm looking for something like that, but i wonder if there isn't exist a function to do this

Comment: Maybe you can make do with the output of `mat.nonzero()`?

Comment: [list(mat[i].nonzero()[1]) for i in range(mat.shape[0])] "for line in mat" doesn't work

Comment: @zedouard: it should, unless there's an edge case I haven't thought of.  In what way did it not work?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
>>> [mat.indices[mat.indptr[i]:mat.indptr[i+1]]
     for i in range(len(mat.indptr) - 1)]
[array([0, 2]), array([2]), array([0, 1, 2])]
```

Not sure what this is supposed to be useful for, though.  Chances are there are better ways of achieving what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is very CSC/CSR-format specific. @DSM's `nonzero`-based answer will work for all `scipy.sparse` types.

Comment: @larsmans:  The important difference is that this answer gives the sparsity pattern, while DSM's answer gives the non-zero elements.  I don't think there's a type-agnostic way to get the sparsity pattern.  Also note that DSM's answer doesn't work for `coo_matrix` and `dia_matrix`.